# R Rename Variables Following Convention

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
DATA = data.frame(a1trt = c(1,2),
                  a2trt = c(5,9),
                  b1for = c(0,9),
                  b2for=c(5,6),
                  b3for = c(NA,8))


WANT = data.frame(trt1 = c(1,2),
                  trt2 = c(5,9),
                  for1 = c(0,9),
                  for2=c(5,6),
                  for3 = c(NA,8))
```

Basically I have DATA and for all variables names I want to remove EVERYTHING that comes before the number, and then move the number at the end..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
names(DATA) <- gsub(".*(\\d)(.*)", "\\2\\1", names(DATA))
```

Using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

DATA |>
  rename_with(~ gsub(".*(\\d)(.*)", "\\2\\1", .x))
```

**Output**

```
  trt1 trt2 for1 for2 for3
1    1    5    0    5   NA
2    2    9    9    6    8
```

Comment: What does "\\2\\1" do?

Comment: @AndreWildberg has a good explanation. In regular expressions `()` captures a group and `\\1` and `\\2` refer to each respective capture group.

Comment: so in this case the first capture groups are the letter and the number?

Comment: Nothing from before the number is captured: `.*`. Then the digit is captured first `(\\d)` so it is referenced with `\\1`. Everything after the digit is also captured `(.*)` and it is referenced with `\\2`.

Comment: @AndreWildberg no worries! I had referenced your explanation since it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub` with 2 capture groups `\\1` and `\\2`. Here, `(\\d+)` captures the number (one or more through +) and everything that follows `(.*)` and outputs these in the desired order.

```
colnames(DATA) <- sub(".*(\\d+)(.*)", "\\2\\1", colnames(DATA))

DATA
  trt1 trt2 for1 for2 for3
1    1    5    0    5   NA
2    2    9    9    6    8
```

Comment: Oops, haven't seen that there was already a dplyr answer. Gonna remove mine.